# How to update a chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest after changed filters

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a small Google Chrome extension that should block requests to some websites from the array. After I clicked on some button, one item from the array of websites should be removed and it should be available from the browser, but it is not.

I tried to create a listener (`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()`) that takes an array with sites as a filter. Then I deleted one element from the array and deleted the listener(`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener()`). Then created a new listener with a new set of sites.

```
let listURL = [
    "*://*.facebook.com/*",
    "*://*.yandex.ru/*"
];

function blockRequest(details) {
    return {cancel: true};
}

function updateFilters(urls) {
    if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest)) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {
        urls: urls
    }, ['blocking']);
    chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged();
}

updateFilters(listURL);

document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateFilters(["*://*.yandex.ru/*"]);
});
```

I expect that after clicking on the button (`#delete`) the http://facebook.com will be accessible from the browser.

Comment: Without an [MCVE](/help/mcve) I can only guess this code is a part of the browserAction popup script, in which case the problem is that the popup runs only when shown. If my guess is wrong, the code doesn't make sense as it mixes parts that should reside in the background script and parts that deal with DOM that should be inside the popup script. The re-registering part itself seems correct.

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference between app.js and background.js. But I have just one script - this

Comment: Well, you need to understand it. See the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can you be a little bit more positive? I asked you because I need help.
You can answer how do I override the listener by pressing a button?

Comment: I guess I can't because I believe I'm as positive as I can get. You really need to understand the architecture. Then it'll be obvious that you need a background script and a popup script separate. Uhm, I haven't mentioned messaging, which you will need to communicate between the two scripts.

Comment: From the link you gave me, I found out that there are two kinds of scripts (context and background). And I read about the messages through which they can be linked. But the question remains, will the removal and installation of a new listener work if I implement such a model?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work when placed in a properly declared background script.